# How can we check reference equality for a type that implements equality operator?

Tags: c#, equality

In C#, how can we check reference equality for a type that implements equality operator?

```
class C
{
    public int Val{get;set;}
    public static bool operator ==(C c1, C c2)
    {
        return c1.Val == c2.Val;
    }
    public static bool operator !=(C c1, C c2)
    {
        return c1.Val != c2.Val;
    }
}
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        C c1=new C(){Val=1};
        C c2=new C(){Val=1};
        Console.WriteLine(c1==c2);//True. but they are not same objects. 
                                  //How can I Check that?
        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Um, `x == y`? It's not really clear what you're asking...

Comment: What is object equality? The same data or the same reference?

Comment: If you mean referential equality (the same memory address), you can use `object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean equality by reference, you may use the `Object.ReferenceEquals` static method even if the `==` operator was overloaded for the current type to work otherwise:

```
Object.ReferenceEquals(obj1, obj2);
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this answer, but I just want to mention that you can also just upcast the two operands (or just one, actually) to `object`, so use `(object)obj1 == (object)obj2`. In that case the user-defined overload `operator ==(C c1, C c2)` does not apply, and the overload `(object, object)` defined by the C# language itself is used. (Neither technique is meaningful for value types; boxing.)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: that's what really the `ReferenceEquals` method do :), because as far as I know the implementation is the following:   `public static bool ReferenceEquals(object objA, object objB) { return objA == objB; }`

Comment: Surely they do the same thing. I just wanted to say that there are two ways of writing that.

Answer (score 0):

What does object "object equality"?

If by "how can we check object equality for a type that implements equality operator?", you actually mean "how can we check object equality for a type that implements `IEquatable<T>`", the short answer is...*however you want* (with some caveats).

The documentation for [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) offers some guidelines. You might also want to implement [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as well. And if you implement both `IEquatable<T>` and `IComparable<T>`, it would make sense if your `Equals()` method returns `true` for all the cases where your `CompareTo()` method returns 0, and for your `Equals()` method to return `false` for all the cases where your `CompareTo()` method returns a non-zero value.

Further, you might want to ensure that you properly override `==` and `!=` to provide the same behaviour as calling Equals().

Comment: Sorry. I meant reference equality. Edited the question.